# How to change the path for local backend state when using workspaces in terraform?

Tags: automation, terraform

What is the expected configuration for using terraform [workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html) with the [local backend](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/local.html)?

The local backend supports workspacing, but it does not appear you have much control over *where* the actual state is stored.

When you are not using workspaces you can supply a `path` parameter to the local backend to control where the state files are stored.

```
# Either in main.tf
terraform {
  backend "local" {
    path = "/path/to/terraform.tfstate
  }
}

# Or as a flag
terraform init -backend-config="path=/path/to/terraform.tfstate"
```

I expected analogous functionality when using workspaces in that you would supply a directory for `path` and the workspaces would get created under that directory

For example:

```
terraform new workspace first
terraform init -backend-config="path=/path/to/terraform.tfstate.d"
terraform apply
terraform new workspace second
terraform init -backend-config="path=/path/to/terraform.tfstate.d"
terraform apply
```

would result in the state

```
/path/to/terraform.tfstate.d/first/terraform.tfstate
/path/to/terraform.tfstate.d/second/terraform.tfstate
```

This does not appear to be the case however. It looks like the local backend ignores the path parameter and puts the workspace configuration in the working directory.

Am I missing something or are you unable to control local backend workspace state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an undocumented flag for the local backend `workspace_dir` that solves this issue.

The documentation task is tracked [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21391)

```
terraform {
  backend "local" {
    workspace_dir = "/path/to/terraform.tfstate.d"
  }
}
```